How should I carry my motorcycle helmet when entering an indoor area?
I have a small scooter that goes at a maximum speed of 45 km/h, it solves all my problems in this city. Where should I put my motorcycle helmet when entering a closed space (school, market, gym, hospital etc.)?
There is a small seat under the seat of the motorcycle, but the helmet does not fit there and I did not take any luggage or boxes etc. in the back so as not to look like a courier.
Right now, after parking the motorcycle, I tie the helmet to the waist of my pants from the neck part (so that I can use my hands). What is a healthier and more pleasant version of this?

Until you clarify all below, my only reason for doubting everything about this Question is bogus, and you're a troll, is that the spelling of your name seems not English but Central or Eastern European…
Will you please edit your Question to either drop, or explain the relevance of your scooter being small, or having a maximum speed?
Can you say how that changes where you should ever put your helmet, entering a closed space or not?
Does a small 'seat under the seat' in fact mean a 'space'?
Why not simply carry the helmet in one hand?

You can use a small backpack to carry the helmet. Some advantages are

It's easier to carry than a helmet swinging from your waist.

It is unobstrusive – you don't seem to be an obvious biker.

It is protected from knocks and scratches.


You can store the backpack in the small compartment that isn't large enough for the helmet.
A small backpack is a common and unremarkable sight, whereas bikers may sometimes annoy people who have a stereotyped attitude problem.

If you have to carry other things: school material, gym clothes etc, then use a larger backpack.

If it's a full-face helmet, carry it on your elbow.
Put your arm in through the neck opening and out through the face opening, with your elbow inside the helmet.
Of all the ways to have to carry a helmet, I generally found this the most convenient.

The OP does ask for an unobtrusive method.  This doesn't qualify.

No they don't, they ask for a healthier and more pleasant version.  I would argue this is more pleasant than strapping it to your waist.

If the design of the scooter allows, "chain" the helmet to the scooter with a chain typical for securing bicycles. I do not have the knowledge to recommend a chain that cannot be quickly opened.
